Among many subfolders, find CSVs starting with a given string and within ZIPs or not, and merge them while adding their names in a new column with R
In a folder (path = "D:/DataLogs/), I have several subfolders. Inside these subfolders, I would like to retrieve all the csv starting only with "QCLog" and merge them (rbind) into a single data.frame, while creating a first new column including the full path/name of these QCLog csv.
The two difficulties are:

In some subfolders, there may be csv (starting with QCLog or not) directly accessible and others located in several zip files (examples within the green rectangles below).
All CSVs have the same number of columns (n=66) and the same headers. However, some headers contain accents or symbols, almost every second column (one in two) has the exact same header name, and some columns are empty (no NAs).

Is this feasible?
Thanks for help


By full name do you mean the fully qualified name, with their absolute paths?

Yes, I mean the full path/name

The following code, although a bit long, works fine and fast:
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# paths
main_path <- "D:/DataLogs/" # target directory
zip_path <- "D:/DataLogs/Zip_files/" # subfolder where the zips will be unzipped

# specific string of csv file name
str_csv <- "QCLog"

# list csv
csv_nozip_list <- list.files(main_path, paste0(str_csv, ".*\\.csv"), recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) # list of QCLog csv that ARE NOT within zip
zip_list <- list.files(main_path, "\\.zip", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) # list of all csv -including QCLog- that ARE within zip
unzip_files <- lapply(zip_list, unzip, exdir = zip_path) # unzip all CSV in the zip_path subfolder
csv_zip_list <- list.files(zip_path, paste0(str_csv, ".*\\.csv"), recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) # list only QCLog that have been decompressed in zip_path

# read matching files while adding a new filename column
csv_nozip_read <- lapply(csv_nozip_list, function(x) {data.table(fread(x), "filename" = x)})
csv_zip_read <- lapply(csv_zip_list, function(x) {data.table(fread(x), "filename" = x)})

# rbind lists
csv_nozip_rbind <- data.table::rbindlist(csv_nozip_read)
csv_zip_rbind <- data.table::rbindlist(csv_zip_read)

# rbind selected csv
dat <- rbind(csv_nozip_rbind, csv_zip_rbind) |>
  distinct() |> # if needed
  relocate(filename)


This is really nice. One alternative that is worth knowing for the future is the idcol parameter in rbindlist. Docs: "If the input list has names, those names are the values placed in this id column, otherwise the values are an integer vector 1:length(l). See examples." setNames(csv_nozip_list) |> lapply(data.table::fread) |> rbindlist(idcol = "filename")

Something like the following might work. Untested.
# function to unzip the csv files 
# first get the csv filenames, then extract them to a temp directory
# return one data.frame only
read_csv_in_zip_file <- function(filename, tmpdir) {
  csv_files <- unzip(filename, list = TRUE)[["Name"]]
  i <- grep("QCLog.*\\.csv", csv_files)
  fls <- unzip(filename, files = csv_files[i], exdir = tmpdir)
  df_list <- lapply(fls, read.csv)
  res <- Map(\(x, f) {
    x$filename <- basename(f)
    x
  }, df_list, fls)
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

# where to put the unziped files
tmp_dir <- tempdir()

path <- "D:/DataLogs"
pattern <- "QCLog.*\\.csv|\\.zip"
fls <- list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

df_list <- lapply(fls, \(f) {
  if(grep("\\.zip", f)) {
    read_csv_in_zip_file(f, tmp_dir)
  } else {
    res <- read.csv(f)
    res$filename <- f
    res
  }
})

# one data.frame only
df_all <- do.call(rbind, df_list)

# final clean up
unlink(tmp_dir, recursive = TRUE)
# rm(df_list)


Thanks but I get the message "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :  More columns than column names". If it is related to the structure of the csv, is there a way to get around it?

Alternatively, since some columns in the CSVs are empty (but with a header name nonetheless), is it possible to select only the ones of interest?

@denis Yes, it is. Before returning from the functions, subset the df's. For instance, res[c(1, 2, 4)] as the functions' last instruction returns columns 1, 2 and 4.

Despite this, I still get the error "...more columns than column names". It seems that this error is related to the fact that some CSVs -not all- already have separate columns (as if the 1st column had been previously deconcatenated). I would either have to reconcatenate them all, or convert them all to xlsx, is this possible with lapply or something else?

@denis You will have to see what is in those files, exactly. It now seems you are not sure they all have the me structure. Are the differences only between csv files and the compressed csv's in zip files?

All CSVs have the same number of columns (n=66) and the same headers. However, some headers contain accents or symbols, and almost every second column (one in two) has the exact same header name. The trick would be to get rid of the accents and symbols while adding a suffix number for similar headers.

Based on the statements in the question we assume that each csv file

has a path of D:/datalogs/*/QCLog*.csv or
is in a zipfile with the same path except having .zip extension and the filenames also starts with QCLog

and that all csv files have the same columns and headers. If these are not satisfied it may or may not work.  If not you may be able to modify the code based on what you actually have using your knowledge of what you actually have or you may be able to edit the files to put it in the form stated in the question.
Whether this works will depend on what you actually have but its heuristic often does work and it is short.  If it is ok to have the row names identify the source as opposed to a separate column then we can omit the last two lines.
library(rio)
library(tools)

root <- "D:/datalogs/*"
csv_files <- Sys.glob(file.path(root, "QCLog*.csv"))
zip_files <- Sys.glob(file.path(root, "*.zip"))
L <- c(import_list(csv_files), import_list(zip_files))
L <- L[ grep("QCLog.*csv", names(L)) ]
dat <- do.call("rbind", L)

dat$id <- file_path_sans_ext(rownames(dat))
rownames(dat) <- NULL

Update
Added code to ensure only QCLog...csv files are used in dat.

Thanks, but the problem is that zip_files -and thus L too- contains other csv called differently and which are completely different in their structure (number of columns, headers). In the zip_files line of code, is there a way to search for the csv called specifically 'QCLog...' inside all zip?

It doesn't work because the paths listed in zip_files are of type D:/Datalogs//.zip and do not contain the name of the csv subfiles

If the problem is that the name is a file path and not just a filename then use grep as shown in the updated code in the answer.

It works well up to L[grep("QCLog", names(L))] which generates a large list (256 elements) but L <- L[ grep("QCLog.*csv", names(L)) ] generates a list of 0 elements, curiously. Anyway, in my case, this is not a problem because there are no QCLog files other than csv (in other words, all QCLog files are necessarily csv).

The last line dat <- do.call("rbind", L) processes but stops with this alarm (translation from French):
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...):
argument column numbers do not match
Error during wrapup: invalid multibyte string at 'me'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); calling an 'abort' restart

Arghhh...it appears that among the 265 elements of the list generated by L[grep("QCLog", names(L))], many element are not QCLog csv and have not the same number/headers.

See if rbindlist(L) from data.table or bind_rows(L) from dplyr work.

The line L[grep("QCLog", names(L))] does not work finally; the list includes others csv, not only QCLog csv, so since csv within L have not the same number of columns/headers, we cannot rbind them.

We're almost there, but unless you really want to, don't waste any more time. My code works well thanks to fread which works perfectly despite the difficulties mentioned above; even if it is a bit long code, it is extremely fast (more than the first steps with rio and tools which are a bit longer).

rio alredy uses fread for .csv files so that is not a difference.

indeed I read that, but the import_list function used in your code was a bit longer though

The sticking point in your code was that the import_list(zip_files) line stopped at the name of the zips, not the CSVs included in those zips -> grep couldn't find the QCLog CVSs specifically, and so L listed all CSVs indifferently (thus not mergeable). Thanks anyway, I learned a lot.

Suggest you create a small reproducible example that illustrates the problem and post it to the rio issues page. https://github.com/gesistsa/rio/issues
